# Django / Apache / WGSI

Tags: django, apache, django-wsgi

Im trying to configure apache and django via wsgi. However Im running into errors around import settings such as :

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'mymask.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named mymask.settings
```

### layout

My site and my app are within the following structure :

```
[root@Fileserver opt]# tree django/mysite2/
django/mysite2/
|-- 1
|-- README
|-- TEMPLATES
|   |-- contact_form.html
|   |-- timedate.html
|   |-- whatmask_input.html
|   |-- whatmask_input.html.bak
|   |-- whatmask_output.html
|   `-- whois_output.html
|-- __init__.py
|-- __init__.pyc
|-- apache
|   `-- django.wsgi
|-- manage.py
|-- mymask
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- __init__.pyc
|   |-- models.py
|   |-- models.pyc
|   |-- tests.py
|   |-- views.py
|   `-- views.pyc
|-- settings.py
|-- settings.pyc
|-- static
|   |-- css
|   |-- images
|   `-- js
|       `-- jquery.js
|-- timedate
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- __init__.pyc
|   |-- models.py
|   |-- tests.py
|   |-- views.py
|   `-- views.pyc
|-- urls.py
`-- urls.pyc
```

### apache/django.wsgi

```
import os, sys

path = '/opt/django/mysite2/mymask'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mymask.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi

application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

### httpd.conf

```
# Django

Alias /media/ /opt/django/mysite2/media

<Directory /opt/django/mysite2/media>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/django/mysite2/apache/django.wsgi

<Directory /opt/django/mysite2/apache>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/django/mysite2/apache/django.wsgi
```

Any ideas ??

Answer (score 2):

Settings isn't in `mymask`, it's in the base `django/mysite` directory. So you should add that to `sys.path`, and set your `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to just `settings`.

Comment: ok cool. I just amended that but I am now getting a django error saying : 

Exception Value: No module named mysite2.urls

Comment: You probably need to modify your ´ROOT_URLCONF´ in settings.py to point to just 'urls' instead of 'mysite2.urls'.